# Equation issue in the LaTeX

Tags: equations, amsmath

I've recently started using LaTeX. I am struggling with writing the equation below.

[image]

This is what I've tried:

```
\[
\mu\Big[\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
(r\frac{\partial v_{r}}{\partial r}) +\frac{1}{r^{2}} 
\frac{\partial^{2} v_{r}}{{\partial \theta}^{2}}
+\frac{\partial^{2} v_{r}}{{\partial z}^{2}} -\Big]
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try and where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Maybe you should read [lshort](https://ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english) at first!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With use of the `derivative` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{derivative}

\begin{document}
\[
\mu \biggl[ 
\frac{1}{r}\pdv{}{r}\biggl(r \pdv{v_r}{r}\biggr) + \frac{1}{r^2}\pdv[order=2]{v_r}{\theta} + \pdv[order=2]{v_r}{z}
\biggr]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you are typesetting a lot of partial derivatives, you may want to create a macro to make your code simpler.

You could use

```
\newcommand{\pdif}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial{#3}^{#1}}}`
```

Which takes two required arguments (which could be empty) and one optional argument. So `\pdif{}{r}` will produce `∂/∂r`, `\pdif{v}{r}` will produce `∂v/∂r`, and `\pdif[2]{v}{r}` will produce `∂²v/∂r²`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\pdif}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial{#3}^{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\mu\Bigl[\frac{1}{r}\pdif{}{r}\bigl(r\pdif{v_r}{r}\bigr)+\frac{1}{r^2}\pdif[2]{v_r}{\theta}+\pdif[2]{v_r}{z}\Bigr]$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

your equation is cut off, but I think that's it...

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    
\begin{document}
    
\[
\mu \left\[ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( r \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 v_r}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v_r}{\partial z^2}   \right\]
\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.8 \mu \left\[`